# Formatting code in Netbeans to printable format

Tags: netbeans, code-formatting

I am writing Java class file using NetBeans and I use ALT+SHIFT+F for auto formatting.However, This is not wrapping the code to be printable in single page.

How to change customize Formatting settings so that when i do auto formatting the code gets formatted as such it can be printable in single page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of  different ways to handle this:

If you go to `Tools` -> `Options` , Select `Editor` at the top and the `Formatting` tab, select `Java` in the `Language` drop-down list and `Wrapping` in the `Category` drop-down list. There are many options that make the auto-formatting break more lines by switching (`Never` to either `Always` or `If Long` ) which would keep line lengths shorter but still not guarantee that a really long line doesn't extend off the page. It would probably have to break the syntax of Java in order to always  be able to break those lines.

Another option would be to leave auto-formatting alone and just adjust the Print options. Select the text file. Go To File -> Print .... On the first dialog click `Print Options`. On that dialog click the `Wrap Lines` checkbox and/or change the zoom to print in fewer pages.

Comment: Thank you. i went to editor and changed wrapping setting for every option to  If Long. Now everything gets wrapped when i do ALT+SHIFT+LEFT. Except for the comments, if they too long its not getting auto-formatted.